# Store Hive output as textfile

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am creating a external table as follows

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=false;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result_table (uid STRING) partitioned by (pub_year STRING, edition_code STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/output_new/';

insert overwrite table result_table partition (pub_year, edition_code) select uid, pub_year, edition_code from combined_union_table;
```

The "Type" in s3browser is "File" and not "txt".

but when i describe the table it says

"OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"

The result files are used by shell scripts which cant read part files,

How can i get the final results stored in ".txt" format?

**Note:** hive version = Hive 2.1.0-amzn-0

Comment: `.txt` is just a filename extension. `HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat` produces a textfile which can be read by any text editor. Did you try reading any of the produced part file?

Comment: i found a workaround for this, just downloaded the entire content on to a ec2 machine and wrote a script to move the files back in to the same folder as text files.